# How to insert content of a file in different fields in mysql database using shell script?

Tags: mysql, shell

I am trying to scan a folder for new files and reading those files and inserting its content into database and then delete file from folder.Till here its working but the issue that the whole content is getting inserted in one field in database.
Below is the code:

```
   inotifywait -m /home/a/b/c -e create -e moved_to |
   while read path action file; do
     for filename in `ls -1 /home/a/b/c/*.txt`  
     do
        while read line
        do
           echo $filename $line
           mysql -uroot -p -Bse "use datatable; INSERT INTO 
           table_entries (file,data ) VALUES ('$filename','$line'); "
           done <$filename     
           done
       find /home/a/b/c -type f -name "*.txt" -delete
        done
```

Basically the files contains:name,address,contact_no,email.
I want to insert name from file to name field in database,address in address. In php we use explode to split data,what do i use in shell script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be far easier if you use [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) (see the manual for full explanation of syntax and options).

Something like this (though I have not tested it):

```
inotifywait -m /home/a/b/c -e create -e moved_to |
while read path action file; do
  for filename in `ls -1 /home/a/b/c/*.txt`  
  do
     mysql datatable -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' 
       INTO TABLE table_entries (name, address, contact_no, email) 
       SET file='$filename'"
  done
  find /home/a/b/c -type f -name "*.txt" -delete
done
```

edit: I specified `mysql datatable` which is like using `USE datatable;` to set the default database. This should resolve the error about "no database selected."

The columns you list as `(name, address, contact_no, email)` name the columns in the table, and they must match the columns in the input file.
If you have another column in your table that you want to set, but not from data in the input file, you use the extra clause `SET file='$filename'`.

You should also use some error checking to make sure the import was successful before you delete your *.txt files.

Note that LOAD DATA INFILE assumes lines end in newline (`\n`), and fields are separated by tab (`\t`). If your text file uses commas or some other separator, you can add syntax to the LOAD DATA INFILE statement to customize how it reads your file. The documentation shows how to do this, with many examples: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html I recommend you spend some time and read it. It's really not very long.

Comment: Thank u sir.But  those file contain data as :abc
xyzcity
111111
a@gmail.com    .This data is seperated by new line.

Comment: so how to individually insert it ?

Comment: Why do you need to insert each row individually? You wrote a loop to insert all the lines in the file. That's what LOAD DATA INFILE does—in one command for the whole input file, instead of line by line.

Comment: OK sir.I never worked on shell script before so don't know much about it.i tried wit the code edited by you but i am getting this error: ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected

Comment: all the data is getting inserted in 1st field i.e name field only.issue remain same as earlier

Comment: See my edits above. I recommend you read the manual page I linked to.

Comment: Thank you sir its working.SET file='$filename' inserts file name along with its path.is it possible to insert only file name in 'file' field ?

Comment: All the issues are solved.Thank you Bill Karwin sir your suggestions were helpful.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Remember to click the 'accepted answer' for my answer if this was the solution for you.